# Wake on Lan to PXE then boot fails if PXE isn't selected

Tags: wake-on-lan, pxe

We are having an issue when we use Wake-on-LAN our desktops. In the Bios, we set Wake on Lan (under power management) to 'Lan with PXE boot'. If we WOL, the computer will wake, and attempt a PXE boot. If a user doesn't interact with the process, PXE will time out after several seconds (specifically, the screen says 'Press F8 to view menu and it counts down). If F8 is not pressed, then the computer should exit PXE and boot from the hard disk. Once PXE ends, it says 'Auto-Select: Local boot' and then exits the NIC's boot agent. We then get a message: 'No Boot Device Found. Press any key to reboot the machine.' If we reboot the machine, it boots from the hard disk just fine.

I'm wondering if I've missed anything to allow the hard drive to successfully boot when we don't select to use the PXE boot functionality. PXE works when we select an option off the F8 menu. I have updated the BIOS firmware and in all other respects, the computer seems to function as desired, it is just this one error.

Hardware: Dell 7060/7070 desktops using the built in Intel NIC. PXE server created via Ivanti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that from what we can tell, the functionality of the 'LAN with PXE boot' is to boot from PXE. If I don't have any scheduled tasks for the workstation then there is 'no boot device found' (since I didn't schedule one). This fails and then stops. The only way we have been able to overcome this is to just set it to allow wake-on-LAN, but not to boot to it. If we want to PXE boot, we have to manually intervene.